# how to checkout to the master branch

Tags: git

```
pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s)
```

I am unable switch to the master branch even I have created a file in that. Please help me to solve the problem.

```
git checkout -b branch name
mkdir folder name
touch filename

git checkout master
```

Comment: Did you actually run `git checkout -b branch name`? That seems like you should have replaced "branch name" by somthing meaningful.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch --list`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one regular situation when this can occur :

if you start from a brand new, empty repo (you just ran `git init` and haven't done anything else yet), the starting branch (named `master` by default) does not exist yet -- you may see that `.git/HEAD` says `refs: refs/heads/master`, but `git branch --list` will have an empty output.
The branch will be created only when you create the first commit.

You will actually see that, in this starting situation, even without "creating" a new branch, `git switch master` (*note*: that's the new `git checkout master`) will also fail.

---

In an empty repo, `git switch -c <branch_name>` works, but is does just change the name stored in `.git/HEAD` -- it still doesn't create an actual branch.
(*note*: `git switch -c <name>` is the new `git checkout -b <name>`)

To actually create a branch in a new repository, on top of creating files on disk, you need to also create your first commit, that is: at some point, run :

```
git add <some files>
git commit
```

From then on, you will have an existing branch.
And if you have changed the name of your first branch, `master` won't exist -- you will need to create it, using `git switch -c master` for example.

Once you have an active commit, `git switch -c` will start actually creating branches.

---

You didn't provide more details in your question, but here is a guess: are you working in a fresh new repository, with no commits yet ?